# Floating divs inside inline-block parent goes down on resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I have 2 floating divs, `inner-left` and `inner-right` inside parent container `inner-container`.

`inner-container` is set to `display: inline-block;` to have it's width to be equal of width of it's children.

The problem is, when I resize the window, `inner-right` div goes down and only then starts to resize itself.

How do I `inner-right` make it stay on the same line with `inner-left`, and, in the event of window resize, to resize instead of going down?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="inner-left"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></div>
        <div class="inner-right"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In justo orci, rutrum nec feugiat sed, ultrices non dolor. Aliquam laoreet.</strong><br>
    Vivamus purus metus.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: #f0fff0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #bce2c1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.inner-container {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #bce2c1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.inner-left {
    float:left;
    width: 60px;
}

.inner-left img {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}

.inner-right {
    float:right;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/acidonyx/naw6ojwe/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well just remove `float: right` from `.inner-right` and your problem will be solved.

```
.inner-right {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

---

to solve your other problem you can do

```
.inner-right {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: its almost what I need, but for some reason first row in `inner-right` (the bold one) is breaking closer to the end (after word "Aliquam" in jsfiddle) and not extended all the way to the right. - https://jsfiddle.net/acidonyx/naw6ojwe/5/

Comment: give inner-container a width of 100% .. and box-sizing: border-box... 

one more cool solution is to give overflow:hidden to .inner-right

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use `flexbox`, here with `inline-flex` to fit your requirement

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f0fff0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bce2c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.inner-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #bce2c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.inner-left img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
.inner-right {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <div class="wrap-container">
    <div class="inner-container">

      <div class="inner-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="inner-right"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</strong>
        <br>Vivamus purus metus.
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the width of `inner-container` same as width of its children?

Comment: @Acidon Updated with a 2:nd sample. Unprefixed `flexbox` works from IE11 and upwards, so if to support older IE (and very old of the other browsers), use my 2:nd sample.

Comment: @Acidon It does stay the same size, or you mean `inner-container` should shrink to its children's size?

Comment: @Acidon Updated my answer. Is that how you meant?

Comment: Here are the results for `flexbox` : jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/acidonyx/1e30b40z/ , image - https://s29.postimg.org/u0go89axz/js1.png . Here is the result for `inline-flex` : jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/acidonyx/1e30b40z/1/ , image - https://s23.postimg.org/478b7itbf/js2.png . Here is what needed - https://s17.postimg.org/z9sz6uxhr/js3.png .

Comment: @Acidon Updated my answer

Comment: Works great now, I am going to up it for sure, already chose the answer from ashish though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try floating `.inner-right` to the left instead, and giving it a width set in a percentage value, like this:

```
.inner-right {
    float:left;
    width: 85%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qrtjg1j2/)

You can use media queries to update the percentage as you need.

Comment: In Jsfiddle first row in inner-right (the bold one) is breaking closer to the end (after word "ultrices " in jsfiddle) and not extended all the way to the right. I need that row to stay by default as one row for as long as the width of `container` allows.